# Python Linked List Center item

Tags: python, arrays, list

I find a linked list code on internet. My question is what's the easiest way to find center item in linked list? Here is the code.

```
class Node:

   def __init__(self,data,nextNode=None):
       self.data = data
       self.nextNode = nextNode

   def getData(self):
       return self.data

   def setData(self,val):
       self.data = val

   def getNextNode(self):
       return self.nextNode

   def setNextNode(self,val):
       self.nextNode = val

class LinkedList:

   def __init__(self,head = None):
       self.head = head
       self.size = 0

   def getSize(self):
       return self.size

   def addNode(self,data):
       newNode = Node(data,self.head)
       self.head = newNode
       self.size+=1
       return True

   def printNode(self):
       curr = self.head
       while curr:
           print(curr.data)
           curr = curr.getNextNode()
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ You copied code from the internet, and when you had a problem you outsourced it to the internet instead of trying to solve it on your own? This is a trivial problem. Show us some code. _Your own_ code.

Comment: Is your problem the algorithm or the python code?  Do you know to keep two iterators.  In a loop, take two steps of iterator A and one step on iterator B.  Repeat this until iterator A reaches the end, at that point iterator B will be half way.  If it's just Python that is holding you back, then what, specifically, is tripping you up?

Comment: First, I said I found this code on the internet. I have a trouble for writing code. Im new in this job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the list twice.

First time, track the total length.

Second time, stop when you reach the middle (length you got from the first traversal/2).

Alternatively, you can use [two pointer technique.](https://leetcode.com/articles/two-pointer-technique/)

EDIT: Since size is an attribute in this particular implementation of linked list, you don't have to traverse through the whole list to get the total length.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have no idea writing this code.